# PHP copy file A if size bigger than size of file B

Tags: php, copy

I want to check with php if the file size of a file in the root folder is bigger than the size of the same file in the subfolder "old". In case the the size is bigger I want to copy the file to the folder old and overwrite the existing file.

```
<?php
$newfile = 'somefile.txt';
$oldfile = 'old/somefile.txt';

if (filesize($newfile) < filesize($oldfile)){
    copy($newfile,$oldfile);
    echo $newfile. 'is copied';
    }
    else {
    echo $newfile. 'is smaller';
    }
?>
```

This code is not making the copy. Could someone correct the code?

Comment: Are files paths corrent? Is the dirrectory with the old file writable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `>` instead of `<`

As of right now you're checking to see if the $newFile is smaller and if so copy it to the old directory.

```
<?php
$newfile = 'somefile.txt';
$oldfile = 'old/somefile.txt';

if (filesize($newfile) > filesize($oldfile)){
    chmod($oldfile, 0777);
    if(!copy($newfile,$oldfile)) {
         echo $newfile. 'is copied and larger';
    } else {
        echo $newfile. 'is larger but could not be copied';
    }
} else {
    echo $newfile. 'is smaller';
}
?>
```

Comment: That's what I want to know too. It's a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: +1 for you, your idea is right, but downvoter expected it as comment

Comment: +1. I don't understand the downvotes too. It's a logical bug you've found but most probably the downvotes are because he's having trouble with copy() function or permission issues (I guess)

Comment: Well if old has chmod 0777 as he says this is probably the issue as copy() allows relative paths

Comment: hm if i give the file old/somefile.txt chmod 0777 it works. unfortunately the file has only chmod 0640. Is there any way can add in the script to change the chmod?

Answer (score 2):

You need `>` to check if `newfile` has greater filesize than `oldfile`.

I'd use [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to to make sure both of the files exist.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$newfile = 'somefile.txt';
$oldfile = 'old/somefile.txt';

if(file_exists($oldfile) && file_exists($newfile)) {

if (filesize($newfile) > filesize($oldfile)){
    copy($newfile,$oldfile);
    echo $newfile. 'is copied';
    }
    else {
    echo $newfile. 'is smaller';
    }

}
else {
    echo "One of the file doesn't exist";
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As Steven already said you would need to change the `<` to a `>` so that it checks that the file is bigger rather than smaller.

However, it seems to me that you are really checking if the file is newer. The file size is not the most reliable way to check if a file is newer. What if some contents were deleted?

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
if(filemtime ($newfile) > filemtime($oldfile))
{
    copy($newfile,$oldfile);
    echo($newfile."copied");
}
else
{
    echo($newfile."not copied");
}
```